# Creating a switch case control instruction

Tags: c, switch-statement

Here's the code

> Write a code to find grade of a student based on the marks obtained by
> him and as the system given below,
>
> ```
> 1. 90-100-->A
> 2. 80-90-->B
> 3. 70-80-->C
> 4. 60-70-->D
> 5. <60-->E
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
    int marks;

    printf("Enter your marks(1-100)\n");

    scanf("%d\n", &marks);

    switch (marks)
    {
    case 1:
        printf("Your Grade is A\n");
        break;

    case 2:
        printf("Your Grade is B\n");
        break;

    case 3:
        printf("Your Grade is C\n");
        break;

    case 4:
        printf("Your Grade is D\n");
        break;

    case 5:
        printf("Your Grade is E\n");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, if I score `90`, I will be getting two grades? `A` and `B`?

Comment: @babon That's what I am asking... How to write the proper code to run it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
  
int main(){
   int marks;
    
   printf("Enter your marks between 0 to 100\n");
   scanf("%d", &marks);
    
   switch(marks/10){
       case 10 :
       case 9 :
           /* Marks between 90-100 */
           printf("Your Grade : A\n" );
           break;
       case 8 :
       case 7 :
           /* Marks between 70-89 */
           printf("Your Grade : B\n" );
           break;
       case 6 :
           /* Marks between 60-69 */
           printf("Your Grade : C\n" );
           break;
       case 5 :
       case 4 :
           /* Marks between 40-59 */
           printf("Your Grade : D\n" );
           break;
       default :
           /* Marks less than 40 */
           printf("You failed\n" );
   }
 
   return 0;
}
```

To find use switch(marks/10) in the switch statement
if your score is 80 then 80/10 so it will jump to case 8.

Answer (score 0):

Let's ignore error handling and range trapping for this answer!

Given the mapping, you could just do an integer division

```
int grade = marks / 10;
```

Then `switch` on `grade` and `case` accordingly (9,8,7,6, default)

int main(){
int marks;

```
printf("Enter your marks(1-100)\n");
scanf("%d\n", &marks);

int grade = marks / 10;

switch ( grade )
{
    case 10:
    case  9: { printf( "Your Grade is A\n" ); break; }
    case  8: { printf( "Your Grade is B\n" ); break; }
    case  7: { printf( "Your Grade is C\n" ); break; }
    case  6: { printf( "Your Grade is D\n" ); break; }
    default: { printf( "Your Grade is E\n" ); break; }
}
```

Note: There are compilers that support a language extension allowing ranges (eg) `case 90 ... 100:` but these are non-standard so should not be encouraged .

For ranges, in C, you will normally need to do an `if-elseif-else` ladder.

```
if      ( marks > 100 ) { printf( "You cheated\n"     ); }
else if ( marks > 90  ) { printf( "Your Grade is A\n" ); }
else if ( marks > 80  ) { printf( "Your Grade is B\n" ); }
else if ( marks > 70  ) { printf( "Your Grade is C\n" ); }
else if ( marks > 60  ) { printf( "Your Grade is D\n" ); }
else /*   marks < 60 */ { printf( "Your Grade is E\n" ); }
```

Comment: Looks like for a score of `90`, the OP wants to get both grade `A` and `B`.

Comment: @Andrew I was unable to understand the switch case can you explain it again more easily

Comment: Extra code added... although shrey has copied my explaination

Comment: @babon... That looks like a specification error... you can't get two grades for a single test - that would be illogical.

Comment: @Andrew So you have provided a solution based on incorrect or illogical specification / requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform `marks` in a number in the range `[1, 5]`. This can be done for example using an array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    unsigned int marks = 0;

    printf( "Enter your marks(1-100): " );
    scanf( "%u", &marks );
    
    unsigned int grades[] = { 0, 60, 70, 80, 90 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( grades ) / sizeof( *grades );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i != N && marks < grades[N - ++i] );

    switch ( i )
    {
    case 1:
        puts( "Your Grade is A" );
        break;

    case 2:
        puts( "Your Grade is B" );
        break;

    case 3:
        puts( "Your Grade is C" );
        break;

    case 4:
        puts( "Your Grade is D" );
        break;

    case 5:
        puts( "Your Grade is E" );
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```